# Is the term "face-lift" perceived negatively?

Tags: word-usage

While working on a software user interface update, I used the term "face-lift".

I was now told to rephrase my sentences and avoid the term "face-lift", because it is associated with mostly negative feelings in American English use.

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face-lift) I am using it according to the second definition:

> 2 : an alteration, restoration, or restyling (as of a building) intended especially to modernize

which doesn't sound bad to me.

Unfortunately, Merriam Webster does neither give me an indicator on how often the term is use, nor how it is perceived.

Can someone confirm that negative sentiment of the term "face-lift" in the US (ideally with a credible source, not only another personal opinion), or is it just a single person's opinion I should not take too seriously?

Comment: It also means: *a cosmetic surgical operation to remove unwanted wrinkles by tightening the skin of the face*. That’s probably why  they told you to change the term.

Comment: @user067531: that's true, it has that meaning as well. How would I have figured out in advance that this first meaning has such a high impact, that the second is about to get lost?

Comment: @close-voters: I explicitly asked for a credible source, not an own opinion

Comment: Yeah, some people tie it the concept of cosmetic surgery (which is where the term originates).  It's come to mean simple "modernization" of, especially, some building, and hence has lost much of the negative connotation.  But it's a matter of perception.

Comment: *On average*, references to an actual person having a face-lift are usually "derogatory" (implying it's "unnatural", and/or that the subject is "vain", among other possible reasons to sneer at the practice). But that's very rarely the case with ***metaphorical*** usages, such as *The building had a face-lift last year, during which the rotting window frames were all replaced.*

Comment: @ThomasWeller What's a credible source to you? A dictionary? Anybody here is going to be looking at the same dictionaries as you. Dictionaries aren't detailed enough to explain subtleties. 'fat' has no negative sentiment mentioned in its entries, but everyone knows that it is an awful thing to call someone fat to their face.  Anyway, 'face-lift' is common enough for 'superficial changes' or 'changes to the look and feel' it's not negative but certainly could be taken negatively. If you were told to reword it, reword it. That's pretty easy, whether you're 'right' or not.

Comment: Let's say that 25% of people in the States perceive 'face-lift' as having a negative tone. The person/s who told you to "avoid the term 'face-lift', because it is associated with mostly negative feelings in American English use" would then be wrong. But their advice still probably sound. // With FF's example, where immediate context forces the metaphorical usage, I think that most people would feel a positive rather than negative connotation. // As immediate context is perhaps key, I feel that finding a 'credible source' might be nigh on impossible.

Comment: @Mitch: I am thinking of a credible source in a scientific way. One thing is to do what I'm told, the other thing is to use language properly. I can and I will change the phrasing within the company, but not necessarily outside the company. For the latter I need to know whether he's right or not.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether you had one

Comment: @ThomasWeller Can you then give an example of a credible source, one that would be sufficient for you?

Comment: @Mitch: like [coca](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) if it comes to frequency of use, maybe some publications of [Unesco Intangible Heritage](https://ich.unesco.org/index.php), or [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249731732_Swearing_in_Modern_British_English_The_Case_of_Fuck_in_the_BNC), I don't know. Anything where some actual research has been done

Comment: @ThomasWeller 1) frequency of use is not going to tell you sentiment (negativity). 2) I highly doubt that there's an academic analysis of the 'negativity' of the specific term 'face-lift'. A minimally aware native speaker's introspection is as good as you're going to get, and ELU is probably the best (which does not necessarily imply good) place to get that.

Comment: @Mitch: these were examples of sources I could imagine as credible. If I had a credible source for "face-lift", I would not need to ask. And yes, ELU might be the best, and that's why I came here, besides the rules that prevent me from asking what I want without including a statement about credible sources, because it will otherwise be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Can you use 'face-lift' in polite or formal situations? Yes. It is more informal than 'cosmetic surgery' (when referring to cosmetic surgery). But it's not about your intention (which definition you choose); it is how it is perceived, what they hear.

Comment: I agree with Mari-Lou's observation that a good facelift is a good thing. The question is how is a face lift perceived? There does not seem to be any authoritative answer to that question. It is quite possible that the OP would be better served offering specifics. For example: "Our new interface improves usability and efficiency and also looks better. Best of all it retains all the old commands that users have been familiar with, so there is no learning curve to deal with."

Comment: I don't know about America, but whether "face-lift" conveyed negative sense, in Britain it would depend on what you were talking about - your boss's wife or the garden shed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Face lift"  (which I have also seen as "face-lift" and "facelift") involves only cosmetic changes, not structural changes are made.

There might be a perception that the face lift has been done to hide some flaws.

In a house it is not unusual to find that vinyl siding is hiding rotting wood.

There is nothing inherent in the term that says it is hiding something, but it is clearly stated that only the surfaces have been addressed.

If someone wanted to say that all the structural issues have been addressed in a house remodel (for example) they might say, "We went down to the studs", which means that they exposed all of the structure.  It does not mean that they addressed all of the deficiencies however (though it is implied).

So if your software face lift only addresses the appearance of the pages and does not make any functional changes, then "face lift" works for me.

You can also "freshen the appearance of the interface" or "update the appearance" or "modernize the appearance" all of which clearly states that only the "look" of the interface is changing.

This can be a good thing.

"We have modernized the look of our interface while retaining all the features and controls that you are familiar with.  No re-learning will be required."

Comment: OP seeks, and ELU requires, 'credible sources, not opinion or unsupported claims that may be opinion. The question to be answered is the general  'Is the term “face-lift” perceived negatively [in the US]?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you think of any possible credible sources that would provide that for anything? Most dictionaries only give such nuance when it's not a nuance, when it is extreme. And I would have great doubts about a sentiment analysis word list.

Comment: @Mitch Of course not. Which is why I didn't give an answer. I stated this in my comment; didn't you read it? It predates yours here. //  I've C-V'd after giving others with even more arcane memories chance to offer a valid answer, as this is now almost certainly POB; have you? // Also, this addresses reasons why some may have negative connotations, not 'How common are such'. Don't you find that a reason to downvote the answer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My agenda is that POB closing is overused. Not all knowable things have been established in writing by some expert -and- corroborated. ELU is the one place to do some of that establishment. If credible source was actually required (that or close/delete the question/answer), then half of all answers and questions should be removed immediately.

Comment: @Mitch And here, I waited over a day before C-Ving, on seeing that both answers failed to address the actual question 'Is there [reasonable] evidence that the term is associated with mostly negative feelings in American English use?' and yet were upvoted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  It's a good answer. It explains why  something that has had a "face lift" (NOT somebody, as some of the answers seem to focus on) could imply the superficial improvements actually mask serious problems that lie underneath. But it could also suggest  simple aesthetic changes that "lift" the appearance, making  the design more pleasing to the eye.  The term "facelift" per se, expresses a positive outcome.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. The question is 'Is the term “face-lift” perceived negatively?' ... 'Unfortunately, Merriam Webster does neither give me an indicator on how often the term is use[d], nor how it is perceived.' ... 'is it just a single person's opinion?' ...'Can someone confirm that negative sentiment of the term "face-lift" in the US (ideally with a credible source, not only another personal opinion) ...Not 'What are some reasons why the term “face-lift” might be perceived negatively?' // Do you know, I'd really like an apology here. I'm getting rather tired.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry if my single comment, which was not posed or meant to sound aggressive in the slightest, upset you so much.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A I'd said it wasn't a good answer, and you countered that it was. It doesn't attempt to answer the actual question, does it? It can't be a good answer, can it? It presents reasonable logic why the term might be seen as having a negative flavour ('There might be a perception that ...'), it says that the answerer finds the term OK, it suggests what might well be better alternatives, but **it doesn't answer the question**.

Answer (score 1):

For an authoritative answer, google “bad face lift”.

Most of the pictures and commentaries are negative and mocking in tone.

Then google “good face lift”, and you’ll find mostly alternatives to the famous surgical procedure.

Such as: https://www.harpersbazaar.com/uk/beauty/skincare/a18717463/facelift-alternative-skin-treatments/

Broadly speaking, **facelift** has more negative connotations than positive. You can use it in a neutral way and everyone will understand your meaning, but many will assume that you’re being ironic or self-deprecating, which may not be your actual intent.

Comment: A good facelift is undetectable, that is why websites focus on the "disasters" not on the positive outcomes. If you see someone's face looking fresher and more youthful than in the past that is a good thing, isn't it? Likewise, if you give a room a facelift, it means you have renovated it, you've made the room look less "tired" (old fashioned) and worn out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is a good strategy to provide evidence that establishes a usage on the positive-negative scale.

Answer (score 0):

While it would probably be okay in that context, I'd change it to be on the safe side. It can be seen as offensive when referring to someone who had plastic surgery. There is sometimes the connotation that something was flawed or that the person undergoing plastic surgery is vain, but the negative connotations of the word would be unlikely to carry over to its use in describing work done on a software program. However, it is a bit slangy, so perhaps you should use the word "improvement" or "update."

Comment: Hello, Rossella. OP asks for data showing how common the negative associations associated with 'face-lift' are in the US.

Comment: Hello, Edwin. Yes. I did see that OP would prefer data. Unfortunately for OP, I do not believe that studies have been done on the connotation of this word. It's always a possibility that some college student somewhere has made this term the subject of a research paper, but usually studies about individual words only occur after the term has significantly changed over the years or is seen as a slur. While I've heard it referred to in a gossipy way that implies scandal ("Did you hear? So and so got a face lift!"), it hasn't changed enough in meaning or become offensive enough to warrant study.

Comment: But (even pertinent and useful) comments that don't answer the question directly shouldn't be posted as answers on ELU. Have you done the tour of the Help Center?

Comment: Edwin, I believe you misread the question. The question portion says, "Can someone confirm that negative sentiment of the term "face-lift" in the US (ideally with a credible source, not only another personal opinion), or is it just a single person's opinion I should not take too seriously?" The use of the word "ideally" tells the reader that, while a source is preferable,  it is not absolutely needed. In this case it is unlikely that a source is available.

Comment: It is very kind of you to want to provide the OP with the type of answer OP would prefer. If one does exist, I trust that you will hunt to the end of the Earth to obtain said source. If it does not exist, I trust that you will begin a study of the term so that you can give OP the ideal answer. I eagerly await your reply to the OP's question.

Comment: I did double-check the guidelines. You'll be glad to know that my post meets the guidelines for answering questions. The guidelines state, "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: The question asks for confirmation of the negative sentiment of the term "face lift" in the U.S. or advice to disregard the other person's opinion. While OP would prefer citations, the use of the word "ideally" makes it clear that this is not a vital part of the question. I answered the question and provided alternative words for the OP's consideration. While character limits made a fuller explanation of the limitations difficult to accomplish, my comments beneath the reply fulfill that purpose.